# Create filename with date and time

Tags: java

I have inherited some Java source code which basically logs binary data to a file. Below is the section creating the file. What I would like to do, instead of calling the file `data.file` i would like to call the file `HOUR-MIN-DD-MM-YY-data.file`.

Please help, any suggestions are welcome.

```
public void run() {
    InputStream inputStream;
    BufferedInputStream bufferedReader = null;
    FileOutputStream writer = null;

    try {
        inputStream = btSocket.getInputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];     

        bufferedReader = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
        File gpxfile = new File(folder, "data.file");
        writer = new FileOutputStream(gpxfile, true);

        long totalBytes = 0;
        ArrayList<Byte> pendingBytes = new ArrayList<Byte>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the SimpleDateFormat class:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Try something like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss"); 
Date date = new Date();
String fileName = dt.format(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Date now = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh mm ss");
String time = dateFormat.format(now);
File dir = new File(time);
dir.mkdir();
```